# C program printf is not working after getchar while loop

Tags: c

this is a task of Dennis´ and Brian´s book about this language, called C

> Exercise 1-13. Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of
> words in its input.

Here is my code (it´s not finished, but I cant continue because I dont know whats going on.):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAXLENGTH   50

int main() {
  int c, wlength;
  int wlengths[MAXLENGTH];

  /* init array with 0s */
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; ++i)
    wlengths[i] = 0;

  wlength = 0;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
        /* Word is finished, increase count for the length */
        ++wlengths[wlength];
        /* Reset the counter for the next word */
        wlength = 0;
    } else {
        /* Word is still going */
        ++wlength;
    }
  }

  printf("RESULTS:\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; ++i) {
      printf("%d\n", wlengths[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and start the program (I also tried gcc)

```
C:\Users\den\Documents\workspace\cexercixe> clang histogram.c
C:\Users\den\Documents\workspace\cexercixe> ./a.exe
```

Then I start to type the following (for testing):

```
a as asd asdf
123 123
```

Output:

```
RESULTS:
0
```

Which makes no sense to me. Can somebody tell me what Im doing wrong? I also tried adding `fflush(stdout)` which didnt change anything.

Thank you

Comment: `EOF` can be _tricky_ to type on a terminal. Have you tried entering some text into a file, then executing `./a.exe < myfile.txt`? And, have you _saved_ this version of the code before compiling the source file?

Comment: This is a great tip, I will try that. Yes this time I actually saved :D

Comment: It looks like you are compiling a program called “linecount”, which is strange for a histogram generator, but consistent with the output you are getting. Are you sure you are running the right program?

Comment: You are right, I tried so many things that I tested if other programs still work. The actual output is different, but also unexpected. I make changes to the question. Good catch though!

Comment: On a Windows terminal, you can use <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to simulate an EOF, on a Linux or other Unix-like, it would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (unless you changed it through `stty`)

Comment: @Serge Ballesta: This solved it! If I type CTRL + Z (ENTER) instead of CTRL + C, it produces the expected output. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a Windows terminal, you can use <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to simulate an EOF, on a Linux or other Unix-like, it would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (unless you changed it through `stty`)

Comment: Could have been a comment but <kbd> does not seem to work in comments...

Comment: No, take your internet points :) Thanks again.